# Left join using merge in geopandas

Tags: attribute-joins, geopandas

Is there a way to do a "left join" when using the "merge" command on a geopandas df to merge by attribute?

The problem I am running into is that I am joining a geopandas df with CA counites to a pandas df that does not contain all the counites. However, I want the final geopandas df to contain all of the counties, but by default the merge command does an inner join. There is no information on the geopandas merge documnetation page: http://geopandas.org/mergingdata.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When merging by attributes, you are actually using the pandas `merge` (or `join`) method or function (see its docstring: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

This method has a `how` keyword to specify whether to do a left/inner/outer/right join:

```
gdf.merge(df, on='key', how='left')
```

Comment: If I run a pandas method on a geopandas df, does it remain a geopandas df or convert to pandas df?

Comment: Where appropriate (it depends on the exact method), it will remain a GeoDataFrame, as it will in this case of `.merge`

Answer (score -3):

Today, it is necessary to call the pandas class methods separately from geopandas.  Therefore the call for pandas.merge would be `geopandas.pd.merge(...)`